# error in step Starting business network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I developed [hyperledger composer tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) with [Setting up a Blockchain Business Network With Hyperledger Fabric & Composer Running in Multiple Physical Machine](https://www.skcript.com/svr/setting-up-a-blockchain-business-network-with-hyperledger-fabric-and-composer-running-in-multiple-physical-machine/) (docker ps:  1st machine 6 services and 2nd machine 2 services are running) and all step are working find.

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna
✔ Installing business network. This may take a minute…
Successfully installed business network tutorial-network, version 0.0.1
```

but i have error in step Starting business network:

```
composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
Starting business network tutorial-network at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins:
userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute…
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Unknown chaincodeType: NODE)
Command failed
```

My connection profile:

```
{
    "name": "hlfv1",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "x-commitTimeout": 300,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300",
                    "eventHub": "300",
                    "eventReg": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "composerchannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer.example.com"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053"
        },
    "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:8051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:8053"
        },
    "peer2.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:9051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:9053"
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "http://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: in your first line of installing network you write  tutorail and in the second when starting the network you write tutorial

Comment: Sorry I copy wrong, now I edit in my question. What is my problem in this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are running Composer v0.19 (the latest version), but that error looks like you have Fabric 1.0.  But Composer v0.19 only supports Fabric 1.1 GA.

Composer v0.19 takes advantage of the fact that Support for Node chaincode was introduced in fabric-1.1.

I think you will need to delete your containers and images and download the 1.1GA version of Fabric, and continue from there.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now its work, You are always save me :D<3<3